# ¿Cómo obtener lista de certificados instalados en mi pc?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Lo que necesitó es obtener esta lista de certificados o elegir directamente el certificado que está dentro del círculo rojo, actualmente con mi código se abre una ventana y elijo el certificado deseado, pero necesitó que la elección se realice si interacción con el usuario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo actual :

```
   public X509Certificate2Collection ElejirCertificado()
        {
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

            X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates;
            X509Certificate2Collection foundCertificates = certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
            X509Certificate2Collection selectedCertificates = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(foundCertificates,
                                                             "Selecciona un certificado.", "Selecciona un certificado de la siguiente lista:", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);

            return selectedCertificates;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si quieres seleccionar uno en concreto, simplemente debes buscar mediante el `Issuer`(Emitido por) o el `Subject`(Emitido para). Puedes usar Linq para seleccionarlo de una manera sencilla, aqui tienes un ejemplo que devuelve el certificado emitido para `NEOTECNOLOGIAS SOCIALES`:

```
public X509Certificate ElegirCertificado()
{
    X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
    X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates;
    X509Certificate2Collection foundCertificates = certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
    var cert = foundCertificates.OfType<X509Certificate>().Where(x => x.Subject == "CN=NEOTECNOLOGIAS SOCIEDAD ANONIMA").First();
    return cert;
}
```

Comment: Hola Pikoh ...Me da un error que dice LA SECUENCIA NO CNTIENE ELEMENTOS

Comment: el sujeto del certificado es este CN = NEOTECNOLOGIAS SOCIEDAD ANONIMA
OU = CPJ
O = PERSONA JURIDICA
C = CR
G = NEOTECNOLOGIAS SOCIEDAD ANONIMA
SN = 
SERIALNUMBER = CPJ-3-101-408861

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC Pues eso el lo que tienes que poner en la parte de `x.Subject ==`:el primer CN de tu certificado. Debe coincidir exactamente o efectivamente te dirá que no tiene elementos. He editado mi respuesta.

Comment: Pikoh.. eso fue lo primero que hice pero aun asi me devuelve el ERROR que te comente ...

Comment: @EfrainMejiasC Entonces lo que debes hacer es poner un punto de interrupción en la linea que empieza con `var cert =...` y examinar que contiene `foundCertificates`. Asi podrás ver que certificados hay en tu coleccion y examinar cual es exactamente el `CN` que debes colocar.

Comment: Pikoh...Funciono perfecto gracias...

Answer (score 0):

Modifique unos detalles de la respuesta de Pikoh

```
public X509Certificate2 ElegirCertificado()
        {
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates;
            X509Certificate2Collection foundCertificates = certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
            X509Certificate2 cert = foundCertificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>().Where(x => x.Subject == "CN=NEOTECNOLOGIAS SOCIEDAD ANONIMA, OU=CPJ, O=PERSONA JURIDICA, C=CR, G=NEOTECNOLOGIAS SOCIEDAD ANONIMA, SN=\"\", SERIALNUMBER=CPJ-3-101-408861").First();
            return cert;
        }
```